# Mindscape Web Workbench generates duplicate CSS files when compiling with Sass

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sass

I have set up Mindscape Web Workbench with my Visual Studio 2010 project so that the compiled SCSS files are outputted to a separate folder. My intended structure is something like this:

```
Styles/ 
| 
|– output/ 
|    |–   toMain.css    
|    |–   toMain.css.map        
|
| – toMain.scss
```

But what I'm getting is 2 outputs, like so:

```
Styles/ 
| 
|– output/ 
|    |–   toMain.css    
|    |–   toMain.css.map        
|
| – toMain.scss         
|    |–   toMain.css    
|    |–   toMain.css.map
```

I've double checked the output settings for the `toMain.scss` file via `Mindscape > Web Workbench Settings` and the only output I see is indeed that file set for the `Styles/output` folder, but I'm still getting the duplicate. I don't have any other extension in VS2010 that handle SASS, and I can't seem to find any information about this issue anywhere. Are there any other settings for the extension that could be causing this?

EDIT: It may be worth noting that I'm using Team Foundation Server with this project - so the outputted CSS is excluded from source control. I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: If you delete the files and re-save, do they re-appear? Just wondering if they are left over from a previous / default config

Comment: Is there anyway you can find out what specific sass CLI command is being run? Any way to tell how it's calling sassc or libsass? It could also be how you set up root and dest. For example, calling `sassc src/main.scss dest/main.css` explicitly will not compile in the same directory. Can you paste in what your IDE's/Mindscape-thingy's settings/options are for the sass module? ...honestly always easier to use the command line for this...

Answer (score 0):

i had that too before.
File with .map extension is use to decode your compressed file, for example you have .js file that you minimize to .min.js, to help decompress your file you can use .map. 
So if you said that .map is shown at your generated folder, it means that you're css it compressed.
So you have 2 options : 
1. do not compress your css file.
2. find the setting to not generate .map file.

im using prepros theres a setting for that.